# Interact with a program via a menu interface in one console but have it print output in another

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to run the below program from the command prompt and have the TimePrinter class print it's output to a separate console. I'd need to be able to invoke it's methods from the menu interface to start/ stop as required.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self.choices = {
            "0": self.quit,
            "1": self.print_time,
            "2": self.stop
            }
        self.timeprinter = TimePrinter()

    def display_menu(self):
        print("""
    Menu

0 - Quit
1 - Display time
2 - Stop
""")

    def print_time(self):
        self.timeprinter.start()

    def quit(self):
        raise SystemExit("\nGoodbye")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            response = input("Enter an option: ")
            try:
                funct = self.choices[response]
            except KeyError:
                print("{} isn't a valid choice.".format(reponse))
            else:
                funct()

    def stop(self):
        self.timeprinter.stop()


class TimePrinter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stop = True

    def start(self):
        self.stop = False
        while not self.stop:
            print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.stop = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Menu().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of your python program in another terminal. You need to specify the terminal number only like this:-[image: Output redirection]